# Pretty print a tree from minimal data input

Tags: java, tree

I'm currently working on an uncrafting tool for minecraft and got a neat output working that shows all the materials needed in a tree. I wonder if the code used to print that tree could be improved somehow. I only have the recursion depth as a measurement and the `ArrayList` gets filled in the same order as seen in the input example below. The output format should also stay the same, I'm quite happy with that. The input format is a bit sketchy though, any ideas on that are appreciated as well.

#### The Algorithm

```
    private static void treeprint(ArrayList<Object[]> tree) {

        ArrayList<String> stem = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tree.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(String.join("", stem));
            Object[] o = tree.get(i);
            int cdepth = (int) o[0];
            String cname = (String) o[1];
            int camt = (int) o[2];

            int ndepth = (int) tree.get(i + 1)[0];
            if (ndepth > cdepth) {
                if (isLastOfDepth(tree, cdepth, i + 1)) {
                    System.out.print("\\---");
                    stem.add("    ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("+---");
                    stem.add("|   ");
                }

            }
            if (ndepth == cdepth) {
                if (isLastOfDepth(tree, cdepth, i + 1)) {
                    System.out.print("\\---");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("+---");
                }

            }
            if (ndepth < cdepth) {
                System.out.print("\\---");
                for (int j = 0; j < cdepth - ndepth; j++) {
                    stem.remove(stem.size() - 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(cname + " x " + camt);
        }

        System.out.println(String.join("", stem) + "\\---" + (String) tree.get(tree.size() - 1)[1] + " x "
                + (int) tree.get(tree.size() - 1)[2]);
    }

    private static boolean isLastOfDepth(ArrayList<Object[]> tree, int depth, int start) {

        for (int i = start; i < tree.size(); i++) {
            int cdepth = (int) tree.get(i)[0];
            if (cdepth < depth) {
                return true;
            }
            if (cdepth == depth) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

#### Test Input

Format is recuresion depth / item name / item amount

```
1 component heat vent 1
2 iron bars 4
3 iron 6
2 heat vent 1
3 electric motor 1
4 coil 2
5 copper cable 8
5 iron 1
4 iron 1
4 tin item casing 2
3 iron bars 4
4 iron 6
3 iron plate 4
2 tin plate 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice solution, my suggestions:

- **Short variable names**: variables like `camt` and `cname` can be extended to `currentAmount` and `currentName`. It's better to have longer names to improve readability. For example, I am not sure what `stem` stands for.
- **Types and input validation**: there are a lot of casting in the methods which are not validated. Accepting an array of `Object` without any validation is a recipe for troubles. Using a class you can solve both problems, something like this:

  ```java
  class Node{
      private int depth;
      private String itemName;
      private int amount;
      public Node(int depth, String itemName, int amount) {
          // Input validation here
          this.depth = depth;
          this.itemName = itemName;
          this.amount = amount;
      }
      // Getters, etc.
  }
  ```

  So this code:

  ```java
  Object[] o = tree.get(i);
  int cdepth = (int) o[0];
  String cname = (String) o[1];
  int camt = (int) o[2];
  ```

  Can become:

  ```java
  Node node = tree.get(i);
  int currentDepth = node.getDepth();
  String currentItemName = node.getItemName();
  int currentAmount = node.getAmount();
  ```

  You can also make the properties of the class `final` to have an immutable node.
- **Constants**: the strings `\---` and `+---` are repeated multiple times. Consider creating constants for such special strings so that they will be easier to change in the future.
- **Functionality**: If the list is not properly built, the tree will not be printed correctly. For example:
  The input:

  ```
  1 a 1
  2 b 1
  3 c 1
  4 d 1
  ```

  Produces the correct output:

  ```
  \---a x 1
     \---b x 1
        \---c x 1
           \---d x 1
  ```

  But if we add one more node in the middle:

  ```
  1 a 1
  2 b 1
  3 c 1
  2 e 1
  4 d 1
  ```

  The output becomes:

  ```
  \---a x 1
    +---b x 1
    |   \---c x 1
    \---e x 1
        \---d x 1
  ```

  Now `d` changed its depth from `4` to `3` and `e` became its father.

  Providing a well-formed list of nodes with corresponding depth is not a simple task if the tree grows in size. A solution might be to create a `Tree` class that knows how to add and remove nodes. Then the `treePrint` method will do a [Pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) scan of the tree and print the nodes on the way.

Comment: Thanks! Var names and constants do need a refactoring. 
As for the `Object[]`: The entries are either internal counters or validated elsewhere. Still a valid point, perhaps a class would still be better for readability.
As for functionality, this is a bug but one that shouldn't occur. The `ArrayList` is generated in order as the tree of recipe dependencies is explored depth-first via recursion. This way, the `cdepth` can only grow by 1 (but shrink to any number >0).